# Python Error TypeError: fit() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X' and 'y'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

My error code is TypeError: fit() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X' and 'y'

This is my code

```
from sklearn import tree

#[height,weight,shoe size]

X = [181,80,44], [177,70,43], [160,60,38], [154, 54,37]

Y = ['male','female','female','female']

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = clf.fit(X,Y)

prediciton = clf.predict([[190,70,43]])

'print'(prediciton)
```

Comment: Change `clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` to `clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()`. Change `clf = clf.fit(X,Y)` to `clf.fit(X,Y)`. Also, your last line of code needs fixing.